# Passing optional console arguments to function in python

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm writing a function that takes three optional arguments from the console.

```
def FizzBuzz(target_number=100, fizz=3, buzz=5):
    
    for i in range(target_number):
        output = "" #This is what the function will return
        if i % fizz == 0: #If a multiple of Fizz, add "Fizz" to output
            output += "Fizz"
        if i % buzz == 0: #If a multiple of Buzz, add "Buzz" to output
            output += "Buzz"
        if output == "": #If neither Fizz nor Buzz is in the output, print number instead
            output += str(i)
        print(output)
```

I got it running with sys.argv:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    FizzBuzz(int(sys.argv[1]))
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
    FizzBuzz(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
else:
    FizzBuzz(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))
```

This approach was tedious and ineffective. Is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: How about just `FizzBuzz(*map(int, sys.argv[1:]))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='FizzBuzz')
parser.add_argument('--target', type=int, default=100,
                    help='Target number (default: 100)')
parser.add_argument('--fizz', type=int, default=3, 
                    help="Multiples of this argument will output 'Fizz' (default: 3)")
parser.add_argument('--buzz', type=int, default=5, 
                    help="Multiples of this argument will output 'Buzz' (default: 5)")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args()
    FizzBuzz(args.target, args.fizz, args.buzz)
```

One advantage of this over converting each element of `sys.argv[1:]` to an integer is that each argument is truly optional - you can pass only `--buzz 7` to use 7 for the last argument and the defaults for the others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
FizzBuzz(*map(int, sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: Or a little bit more readable: `FizzBuzz(*[int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:]])` But this is a matter of personal style :-)